# how to calculate the moving avg for stock in stock market

Tags: stock

I want to cal the moving avg for an etf, also i want to know how that can be cal on the paper? Value is available for 6 period and I want to predict the next value using macd cross.

Comment: A simple moving average is, well, pretty simple, it's the sum of all closing (or otherwise relevant) prices divided by the count of those prices (where the prices are the last `N` values in a sliding window usually). However, most ETF analyses rely on exponential moving averages, which are a tad more complex. You probably should edit your question to make it clear which one you want. And, since this is a programming Q&A site, you probably want to specify the language, otherwise it's just a general math question rather than a programming one.

Comment: So, which [moving average](https://daveskender.github.io/Stock.Indicators/docs/INDICATORS.html#moving-averages) are you referring to?  MACD is basically the difference between a fast and slow Exponential Moving Average.